# Error: you do not appear to have the sources for the 2.6.32-042stab102.9 kernel installed

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, asterisk, voip

I've just bought a new VPS with Cent OS 6.6 installed.
I'm attempting to install Asterisk 11 on this VPS via command line remotely.

I've used the directions [here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+11+Installation+on+CentOS+6) however I get this error: you do not appear to have the sources for the 2.6.32-042stab102.9 kernel installed when running:

```
cd /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete*
make && make install && make config
```

How can I install this kernel and continue my install?

Answer (score 0):

You need kernel-devel package for this kernel:

2.6.32-042stab102.9

Try install vzkernel-devel. Also you can ask your VZ provider support about source of kernel they use.

Answer (score 0):

First update with YUM:

```
yum update
```

Install the kernel headers & kernel devel on CentOS / RHEL:

```
yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers
```

Reboot and attempt to rebuild Asterisk / DAHDI tools, if it still fails check your kernel version with:

```
uname -r
```

And then check the linked kernel source:

```
cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`
```

Check the symbolic link with:

```
ls -l
```

If the link is broken fix it with:

```
ln -s /usr/src/kernels/(kernel-source-dir) build
```